# Navigation controller and Table view with firebase database

Tags: uitableview, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, uinavigationcontroller

I have the code below, it's a simple address book fetching Name, Phone and Mail from a Firebase Database. all this worked perfect, until I added a Navigation Controller to get access to the Navigation Bar and search function.

now my Tableview won't show anything from the database, I don't know what it does, but its the Nav controller that is blocking something... please help!!

UPDATE!!: It's not loading func cellForRow, witch ofcause means that numberOfRows is returning 0... If I insert a brakepoint I can see that Handle gets one name from the Database so they are still connected, but something i interfering.

```
class TableVC: UITableViewController {
var Telefonbog: [String] = []
var Handle: FIRDatabaseHandle?
var Ref: FIRDatabaseReference?
var searchController: UISearchController!
var resultController = UITableViewController()
static var _Mail = ""
static var _Mobil = ""
static var _Navn = ""

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultController)
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
    Ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    Handle = Ref?.child("medarbejder EL").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let item = snapshot.value as? String
        {
            self.Telefonbog.append(item)
            self.reloadInputViews()
        }
    })
}

//opætning af telefonbog i tableview
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return Telefonbog.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let bog = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "bog")
    bog.textLabel?.text = Telefonbog[indexPath.row]
    return bog
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let currentcell = Telefonbog[indexPath.row]
    Ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    Ref?.child("medarbejder EL").child(currentcell).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let Mail = (value?["Mail"] as? String)!
        let Mobil = (value?["Mobil"] as? String)!
        TableVC._Mail = Mail
        TableVC._Mobil = Mobil
        TableVC._Navn = currentcell
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "kontakt", sender: self)
    })
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seem to be ui update problem. When you get the result, update the ui components asynchronously.

Would you try this? (Swift 2.3)

```
// Move to a background thread to do some long running work
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
    Handle = Ref?.child("medarbejder EL").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let item = snapshot.value as? String
        {   //Update ui on main-thread 
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.Telefonbog.append(item)
                self.reloadInputViews()
                /*
                 *  I think your tableView refresh call in "reloadInputViews()"
                 *   If not add this line.
                 *  self.tableView.reloadData()  
                */ 

            }
        }
    })
}
```